# Use AWS AppSync as a target group for AWS Application Load Balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-appsync, aws-application-load-balancer

The question is essentially what's in the title.

Can I create a private AppSync endpoint, create an Application load balancer within my VPC, and have this AppSync endpoint as a target in this ALB (which would make this endpoint unavailable to the outside world)

Or is there any other way of doing something similar to this